How can I solve the issue of 'failed to resolve import "primevue/datepicker"'
enter image description here
I want to use the package in Vue JS - DatePicker from Primevue
The documentation says that you need to install the package using the command - npm install primevue@4.0.0-rc.2. And half on it is work. But I have problem with DatePicker and ToastService on it. I don't see these packages in the folder -> Primevue. And I can’t find instructions to force install these packages in node_modules.
Attached a screenshot of the error.
Please, help
//app.js code
import './bootstrap';
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import InputText  from 'primevue/inputtext';
import DatePicker from 'primevue/datepicker';//PHPStorm show message -> Module is not installed 
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";

import 'primevue/resources/themes/aura-light-green/theme.css'

const app = createApp({});

import router from "./router.js";

app.component('index', Index);
app.component('DatePicker', DatePicker);
app.component('InputText', InputText);
app.component('ToastService', ToastService);

app.directive('styleclass', StyleClass);

app.use(PrimeVue);
app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');

[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "primevue/datepicker" from "resources/js/app.js". Does the file exist?
/var/www/crm/resources/js/app.js:7:25
5  |  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
6  |  import InputText  from 'primevue/inputtext';
7  |  import DatePicker from 'primevue/datepicker';
   |                          ^
8  |  import Button from 'primevue/button';
9  |  import Toast from 'primevue/toast';
    at TransformPluginContext._formatError (file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:49703:41)
    at TransformPluginContext.error (file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:49698:16)
    at normalizeUrl (file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:64260:23)
    at async file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:64392:39
    at async Promise.all (index 6)
    at async TransformPluginContext.transform (file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:64319:7)
    at async PluginContainer.transform (file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:49544:18)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:52366:27)
    at async viteTransformMiddleware (file:///var/www/crm/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:62102:24

Use PHP 8.1 & Laravel 10.
I re-read all the documentation, but unfortunately there is no information there that is suitable for me on this problem.
I tried to find similar problems on the Internet, but did not find anything similar.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

I just installed primevue@4.0.0-rc.2 in a fresh project, and after running npm install I verified that I can see the folder datepicker within node_modules/primevue. I'd recommend verifying that your package.json includes the dependency "primevue": "^4.0.0-rc.2", then deleting your node_modules folder and running a fresh npm install.
As a side note, I would also recommend upgrading to primevue@4.0.0-rc.3 as they patched a few bugs in the DatePicker, as indicated in the release notes.

ok do you have folder node_modules\primevue\datepicker in your project?
They should be there after primevue installation RC1 or RC2 if not - please run again npm install for primevue and look for any errors in output.
If you have folder for datepicker did you run bundle assets step - npm run dev ?

I understand that there should be a folder with datepicker in node_modules, but there isn’t. I removed everything completely, installed it in another project, but the folder with this package is not installed. I even downloaded the entire package from Github and moved the folder to the node_modules, but due to the lack of dependencies, it gives an error. It’s not in the configuration file, and it’s also not correct to write it there manually, I don’t understand how to make it work.
